# Merge and center cells based on another column having duplicate values

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I would like to merge and center values in one column based on duplicate values in another column.

An example of this is below:

[image]

and I would like the following result

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `Dictionary` object to store to-be-merged cells address and the `Union()` and `Merge()` method to merge them:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeThem()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
        dict(cel.Value) = dict(cel.Value) & cel.Offset(, 1).Address(False, False) & ","
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.keys
        Union(Range(Left(dict(key), Len(dict(key)) - 1)), Range(Left(dict(key), Len(dict(key)) - 1))).Merge
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```